# Is it possible to modify cookie from chrome extension content script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

If i have a chrome extension with a content script, is it possible to modify cookie from this content script? Seems that `chrome.cookie` api can't be used from content scripts and setting `document.cookie` don't change it. Following code is intended to delete all cookies, but `document.cookie` is same after it completes:

```
    _.each(document.cookie.split(';'), function(s_cookie) {
      var sName = s_cookie.replace(/=.+/, '');
      var a = sName + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
      console.log(a);
      document.cookie = a;
    });
    console.log(document.cookie); // Nothing changed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the case, then you probably want to inject a script to the actual page's javascript context, i.e.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code:yourFunction.toString()}, callback)
```